# How to make terminal auto-append and prepend quotation marks to pasted texts/links?

Tags: terminal

Kitty terminal can paste links in and auto-append and prepend quotation marks. Try something like yt-dlp [url], and kitty by default makes it so that you dont have to put the quotation marks. How do i replicate this behavior on another terminal emulator such as terminal.app?